# How to find the domain is whether HTTP or HTTPS (with or without WWW) using PHP?

Tags: php, http, url, https, domain-name

I have **million** (1,000,000) **domains** list.

```
+----+--------------+--------------------------+
| Id | Domain_Name  |       Correct_URL        |
+----+--------------+--------------------------+
|  1 | example1.com | http://www.example1.com  |
|  2 | example2.com | https://exmple2.com      |
|  3 | example3.com | https://www.example3.com |
|  3 | example4.com | http://example4.com      |
+----+--------------+--------------------------+
```

- `ID` and `Domain_Name` column is filled.
- `Correct_URL` **column is empty.**

**Question** : I need to fill the `Correct_URL` column.

The problem I face is how do I find the prefix part before the domain. It may either `http://` or `http://www.` or `https://` or `https://www.`

How do I find correctly what is from above 4 using PHP? Please note that I need to run code to all 1,000,000 domains.... So I am looking at a fastest way to check it...

Comment: _“It may either `http://` or `http://www.` or `https://` or `https://www.`”_ … or possibly _all of the above_ …? A site might be set up to respond to all four of those “versions” - or it might redirect to one “main” version. No other way to figure this out, than to make an actual HTTP request (resp. requests, in case a site doesn’t want to answer for some of those addresses at all) … and that this is not going to go quick for 1,000,000 domains should be obvious from the get-go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `cURL` method:

```
$url_list = ['facebook.com','google.com'];

foreach($url_list as $url){

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
    curl_exec($ch);

    $real_url =  curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
    echo $real_url;//add here your db commands

}
```

This one take some times because it take the last redirected url. if you only want to check whether its `http` or `https` you could try this:

```
$url_list = ['facebook.com','google.com'];

foreach($url_list as $url){

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_exec($ch);

    $real_url =  curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL);
    echo $real_url;//add here your db commands

}
```

Comment: This works fine. Thanks But I can't understand how this works. When we tell program to add `https://www.` or `https://` and other in front of domains (facebook.com. google.com)

Comment: And there is a small bug in this too. When we pass fb.com, it display real URL as facebook.com. But it should be displayed as there is no real URL

Comment: well, this is how it works, just imagine you type `fb.com` in a browser and what the final url you get ? so that's what above code does. it return actual redirected url

Answer (score 6):

**There isn't really any way other than making an HTTP request to each of the possibilities and see if you get a response.**

While you assert *"It may either http:// or http://www. or https:// or https://www."*, real world domains may provide zero, some or all or those (as well as various others) and they may respond to requests with OKs or redirects or authentication errors, etc.

HTTP and HTTPS are not attributes of a web application; they are communication protocols handled by the endpoint (the web server, or an application firewall, etc.).

As with any network communications, one must probe the host ("www" is the host in this case), and the port (not necessarily, but most commonly) port 80 and 443 respectively. This probing is a shout, then you wait and see if there is a service listening on the other side.

Comment: ... or simply ban your source IP address.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg — Unlikely unless all the domain names are being hosted by the same entity.

Comment: ... mostly yes , except I pass a bunch of domains/subdomains (.net, .io ,.ca, .com)  in a single load/balancer and security architecture for two of my products. The same snoopers hit on all (observed), but not many times.

Comment: @Quentin How did you make this answer as community wiki?

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson — https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki

Comment: @Quentin Thanks, But Sorry for my mistakes, I wanted to ask WHY did you make this answer as community wiki?

Comment: Because, as answers go, "Just go and look" is too obvious to get credit for.

Comment: There are actually two things here.  Domain/Subdomain, which is DNS, and Protocol.  Determining protocol requires a hit, but determining the subdomain can be accomplished with a DNS query like:  array dns_get_record ( string $hostname [, int $type = DNS_ANY [, array &$authns [, array &$addtl [, bool $raw = FALSE ]]]] )

Answer (score 2):

Given a known url you could make a call to http and/or https versions with `get_headers`, from their you can determine if https is available, if http redirects to https and so on.

Details can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php

Answer (score 2):

So I have had to build a system similar in that we verify user-supplied URLs.

In the end, you need to set an order of priority the recommended order is HTTPS over HTTP and with WWW over without so you end up with the priority list like:

- https://www.example.com
- https://example.com
- http://www.example.com
- http://example.com

As everyone else has said you will need to test for these using cURL.

```
foreach($domainRows as $domainRow){
    $scheme_list = ['https://www.','https://', 'http://www.', 'http://'];
    $bestUrl = false;
    foreach($scheme_list as $scheme){

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $scheme.$domainRow['Domain_Name']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
        curl_exec($ch);

        $real_url =  curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
        if($real_url){
            $bestUrl = $scheme.$domainRow['Domain_Name']
            break;
        }
    }


    if($bestUrl){
        // you have the best URL to use as $bestUrl save it to your DB Row
    }else{
        // the site is not responding to any URL's do you need to do something here?
    }
```

}

Or based on Alexander Holman's answer which I completely forgot about `get_headers` you can do

```
foreach($domainRows as $domainRow){
    $scheme_list = ['https://www.','https://', 'http://www.', 'http://'];
    $bestUrl = false;
    foreach($scheme_list as $scheme){

        $res = get_headers($scheme.$domainRow['Domain_Name']);
        // if you want to allow redirects remove/alter this part as it blocks them.
        if($res && isset($res[0])){
            $statusParts = explode(" ", $res[0]);
            if($statusParts[1] == "200"){
                $bestUrl = $scheme.$domainRow['Domain_Name'];
                break;
            }
        }
        //end of status check
        //replace with below to allow all responses from server including 404
        /*if($res){
            $bestUrl = $scheme.$domainRow['Domain_Name'];
            break;
        }*/
    }


    if($bestUrl){
        // you have the best URL to use as $bestUrl save it to your DB Row
    }else{
        // the site is not responding to any URL's do you need to do something here?
    }

}
```

This code will test in the order of priority and the first one it matches it will stop testing for the others, and if it does not find a working system for it will tell you that.

With thanks to Supun Praneeth as I have taken and augmented there code to better suit your needs.

Comment: I tested this. It always go to the else part (// the site is not responding to any URL's do you need to do something here?). Do you have any idea

Comment: Sorry I bugged the code, `$bestUrl` with `$best_url`