# How to handle file outputs in an array in php?

Tags: php, curl

So I found a solution to a problem I was having, (how to determine a domain protocol) [How to find the domain is whether HTTP or HTTPS (with or without WWW) using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50873547/how-to-find-the-domain-is-whether-http-or-https-with-or-without-www-using-php)

Below are two versions of my code;

The first doesn't work as expected it only echoes out my domains.

```php
<?php
$url_list = file('urls.txt');
    foreach($url_list as $url)
    {

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
    curl_exec($ch);

    $real_url =  curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);

    echo $real_url;
}

?>
```

The Second version of my code gives me an error of how I am supplied my foreach statement...

```php
<?php


      $fn = fopen("urls.txt","r");

    while(! feof($fn))  {
    $url_list = fgets($fn);

    foreach($url_list as $url)
    {

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
    curl_exec($ch);

    $real_url =  curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);

    echo $real_url;
    #echo $result;
    fclose($fn);
        }
    }

?>
```

What can I be doing wrong??

Expected results is this, but when reading the domains from a file;

code: reference --> [How to find the domain is whether HTTP or HTTPS (with or without WWW) using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50873547/how-to-find-the-domain-is-whether-http-or-https-with-or-without-www-using-php)

```php
<?php


      $url_list = ['facebook.com','google.com'];

foreach($url_list as $url){

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
    curl_exec($ch);

    $real_url =  curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
    echo $real_url;//add here your db commands

}

?>
```

Output:

```
test@linux: php domain-fuzzer.php
https://www.facebook.com/http://www.google.com/#
```

Comment: You could use [`file()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php), but use `$fileList = file("urls.txt",FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, just incase anyone would find such an issue here is the code:

```php
<?php   
    $fn = file_get_contents("urls.txt");
    $url_list = explode(PHP_EOL, $fn);

    foreach($url_list as $url)
    {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
    curl_exec($ch);

    $real_url =  curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);

    echo  nl2br("$real_url \n");
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default fgets returns a single current line from the file not an array of all lines of the file.
So, your code will be:

```
<?php
   $fn = fopen("urls.txt","r");

while(! feof($fn))  {
$url = fgets($fn);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; 
rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
curl_exec($ch);

$real_url =  curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);

echo $real_url;
#echo $result;
fclose($fn);
}

?>
```

Comment: Doesn't work, errors out >> 

PHP Warning:  feof(): supplied resource is not a valid stream resource in /root/Tools/domain-fuzzer2.php on line 4
PHP Warning:  fgets(): supplied resource is not a valid stream resource in /root/Tools/domain-fuzzer2.php on line 5
PHP Warning:  fclose(): supplied resource is not a valid stream resource in /root/Tools/domain-fuzzer2.php on line 18